# Inductances in flyback transformer

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, flyback

I am simulating flyback dc-dc converter  in multisim software tool ..

I want to know the difference betweem  primary inductance and magnetising inductance , also secondary leakage inductance?

Answer (score 2):

The primary inductance used to store energy in a fly-back transformer IS the magnetization inductance. Primary leakage inductance is going to be somewhere in the 2% to 10% of Mag inductance and secondary leakage pro rata with the turns ratio.

The above is based on generally using a ferrite cores that are ball-park gapped normally. In the absence of more data from the OP this has to be a generalization.